# Why does Tomcat 7 server stop on Ubuntu?

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7

I have a Digital ocean instance, on which Tomcat7 server is running.

Sometimes it shuts itself down for reasons I don't know. That is, I launch it, work a bit with it, then do nothing with it for several days. Then I try to connect to it, but it's not available and I have to restart it (`sudo service tomcat7 restart`).

I expect it to work (be available) 24/7, unless I shut it down manually. I don't see any stack traces of errors in the log files.

What may be the reason for the server to shut down after a time of inactivity?

Comment: There is seems some memory issues. Does tomcat get required memory ?

Comment: There are a lot of possible answers, and no information to go on here. Have you tried contacting Digital ocean support?

Comment: What are you getting in catalina ?

Comment: @Ved If it was a memory issue, I suppose that I would see `OutOfMemoryError` in the logs. Can it happen that Tomcat is shut down because of memory issues and there is nothing in the logs?

Comment: @Ved When the server is shut down, I a) can't open the URL of Tomcat in the browser and b) the cargo deployer (`mvn cargo:redeploy`) reports an error (connection refused, I think).

Comment: Yes. server may hangup and even not able to print error logs. Try top, ps -ef commands to see exact scenario.

Comment: Just my couple of cents. I had a similar problem with Tomcat couple of years ago, it was related to external process (sshd). Number of such processes increased over time and resulted in high CPU usage and no memory left. In my case it was related to wrong replication configuration for MySQL, but Tomcat silently shut down itself or just stuck. Take a look at CPU/Memory usage with atop/htop (also try to save it to see the history once it fails again) and also use netstat to see if there are lots of connections created for some process.

Comment: You could try setting up a vmstat on the machine, so that it runs every 5 minutes, and redirect the output to a file. Then, next time you see Tomcat is not running, have a look at the file and you might get some clues...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked the technical support of Digital Ocean and found out that there was no swap file in my droplet. It is a likely cause of the problem (when there is no physical memory, processes are killed because no swap file is there).

So I created it using this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-virtual-memory-swap-file-on-a-vps). I'll see whether this will solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too, but adding swap space didn't help.  In my case, tomcat was being stopped by the OOM killer.  Check for this in the system logs (On Ubuntu: `/var/log/syslog`):  "Send sigkill to..."

For help on the OOM killer issue, you could try increasing the priority of your tomcat process: 
    `echo -15 > /proc/PROC_NUMBER/oom_adj`
(where PROC_NUMBER is your particular process).  For more on tuning the OOM killer see http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/servers-storage-dev/oom-killer-1911807.html

You will likely want to tune the starting and max heap sizes, the max permanent generation, and perhaps other parameters of your tomcat. You can do this through the CATALINA_OPTS environment variable, for example:
    `export CATALINA_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx384m -XX:MaxPermSize=256M"`

Both of these helped me.  I also have a cronjob that checks on tomcat and starts it again if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Check your /opt/tomcat/logs/**catalina.out** file size. If catalina.out becomes 2GB in size, tomcat crashes and fails to start without any error message. You need to setup log rotation for catalina.out:

```
sudo apt-get install logrotate
```

Then create

> /etc/logrotate.d/**filename**

Copy the following contents into the above file("filename")

> /var/log/tomcat/catalina.out {   copytruncate   daily   rotate 7
>   compress   missingok   size 5M  }

change cron parameters as you need.